# Hebrew On Tomcat 7 renders gibberish

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, hebrew

I'm writing a servlet hosted on Tomcat 7. It's supposed to stream Hebrew text to the response, but it renders as gibberish or `???`'s. I'm using `PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();` to print.

Can you help?

Comment: What's the character encoding of your stream?

Comment: UTF-8. Works perfect on desktop. Gibrish on Servlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you obtain the writer/output stream and start writing:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Comment: Actually, you have to call that before obtaining the writer object. From the javadocs: 'The setCharacterEncoding, setContentType, or setLocale method must be called before getWriter and before committing the response for the character encoding to be used. '

Comment: yes, sure. I assumed the obtaining and writing as atomic in his case. I'll clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set the character encoding to an encoding that can encode Hebrew?  The default character encoding is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: I have changed the server.xml to:
    <Connector useBodyEncodingForURI="true" 
     URIEncoding="UTF-8" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
but doesn't work.

Comment: Yes what I meant was set the encoding for the servlet programmatically, exactly as Bozho said.  In fact, I wouldn't have posted my answer if I had seen his first.

Answer (score 0):

in tomcat server you should follow instructions from this blog:
http://nirlevy.blogspot.co.il/2009/02/utf8-and-hebrew-in-tomcat.html
this worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Link-only answers are frowned upon in the community -- it's better if you could paraphrase the information in the link instead (you can still cite the website in question if you like).